# Textbox accepting date's from 1900 - 2050 in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a textbox for date of birth. What I am trying here is that user should be able to enter date in the range from 1900 - 2050.

I dont want to use `datepicker`. Please suggest any ideas

Here is my aspx:-

```
<asp:TextBox 
     ID="txtDtOfBirth" 
     runat="server" 
     ToolTip="Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY format"
     autocomplete="off" 
     Width="75" 
     MaxLength="10" 
     onblur="calculateAgeFromCalendar(), 
     dateformat(this.value, this.id)">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Not even jquery datepicker?

Comment: @Shaharyar: No, I am not using any `datepicker`

Comment: provide JS and HTMl code that you tried. with ASP code how can people help you

Comment: @fubo: No, I want to show alert message in Javascript. So cant use `range validator`

Comment: @JSantosh: Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/xxqzkfza/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.I think this is very helpful for you.

```
function CheckDate(elm)
{
    var date  = $(elm).val();

    var year = date.split('/')[2];

    if(parseInt(year)>=1900 && parseInt(year)<=2050)
    {
        // Implement here logic

    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please add date between 1900 to 2050");
        console.log("Please add date between 1900 to 2050");
    }
}
```

Comment: on which property of the textbox should I call this function and check ?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtDtOfBirth" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY format"
                    autocomplete="off" Width="75" MaxLength="10" onblur="CheckDate(this)"></asp:TextBox>

Pass your element in checkdate function.

Comment: I already have one function on `onblur` so could you help me with that..Also check my fiddle for more information  http://jsfiddle.net/xxqzkfza/

Comment: What are you doing with that function? If possible than implement my login in that function.

Comment: you can call two functions like this.`onblur="functions1();function2();"`

Comment: vishal: It is working for me, but after giving alert message i want the focus on the textbox again

Comment: @nadeem, Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

This code will check valid DD/MM/YYYY date format as well as Year boundaries.

```
function dateformat() {

            var isValid = false;
            var minYear = 1900;
            var maxYear = 2050;

            var txtDtOfBirth = document.getElementById('txtDtOfBirth');

            var regex = new RegExp(/^(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/);
            var isValid = regex.test(txtDtOfBirth.value);

            if (isValid) {
                var year = parseInt(txtDtOfBirth.value.split('/')[2]);
                if (year <= minYear || year >= maxYear) {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }

            if (!isValid) {
                alert('Invalid date');
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
var dateFrom = "01/01/1900";
var dateTo = "31/12/2050";
$('#txtDtOfBirth').focusout(function () {
    ValidateDate()
})

function ValidateDate() {
var dateCheck = $('#txtDtOfBirth').val();
var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
var d2 = dateTo.split("/");
var c = dateCheck.split("/");
   
var from = new Date(d1[2], d1[1] - 1, d1[0]); // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
var to = new Date(d2[2], d2[1] - 1, d2[0]);
var check = new Date(c[2], c[1] - 1, c[0]);
 $('#txtDtOfBirth').val(check.getDay()+'/'+(check.getMonth()+1)+'/'+check.getFullYear())// if user enter 31 feb it will insert march 1st 
if (check > from && check < to) {
    $('#txtDtOfBirth').css('border', '1px solid #0f0')
} else {
    $('#txtDtOfBirth').css('border', '1px solid #f00');
    $('#txtDtOfBirth').focus();
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id="txtDtOfBirth" placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY' />
```

Call `ValidateDate()` in onblur as you mentioned in OP